# SQL Multi-distinct

Tags: sql-server, distinct, hiveql

Question: Does anyone have code for a single-table, multi-column, top N, piecewise distinct, Select query?

Suppose you have a new table db..Stuff
Like all tables there are dimensions and measures in Stuff. We always want to know "What are the range of values for column X in table Stuff?" Therefore, you write a SELECT DISTINCT for several different columns in table Stuff.

If you write, SELECT DISTINCT for more than one column

```
select distinct s.colA, s.colB from Stuff as S
```

then you get the combination of colA and colB. That's nice, but it multiplies your results. It wouuld be better if there was a "piecewise" distinct. Where you get distinct colA and join/union it to distinct colA to get a subset representation of what's in table Stuff.

I'm wondering if anyone has SQL code for this.

Comment: If `colA` is distinct what row to pick from `colB`?

Comment: You need to post an example of input data and output results here because the question is a bit too vague as it stands now.

Comment: DISTINCT gets a distinct row not some mismatch of random columns stuffed into a row. You pretty much defined in your question how you would go about getting the distinct values. select distinct colA from Stuff UNION ALL select distinct colB from Stuff

Comment: I think this question shows a misunderstanding of how `DISTINCT` works...if you get ROWS of data back what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

Try following query to get ColA, and all of ColB with comma separator that have some COLA value:

```
select distinct s.colA, 
        STUFF((SELECT ','+S2.ColB
                FROM [Stuff] AS s2
                WHERE s2.ColA=s.ColA
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ),1,1,'') AS ColB
FROM [Stuff] as S
```